# Setting page/respone.body in Capybara used to work in Webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, webrat

I am migrating to Capybara.
One of the problems I have is migrating the pdf step.

This step sets page.body to a parsed pdf.
That way I can use the default cucumber steps.

```
When 'I follow the PDF link "$label"' do |label|
  click_link(label)
  page.body = PDF::Inspector::Text.analyze(page.body).strings.join(" ")
end
```

Ex.

```
When I follow the PDF link "Catalogue"
Then I should see "Cheap products"
```

The error I get is this one:

```
undefined method `body=' for #<Capybara::`enter code here`Document> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setter for body defined in the source in capybara, so you cannot set it externally like that.  Try this (untested):

```
page.instance_variable_set(:@body, PDF::Inspector::Text.analyze(page.body).strings.join(" "))
```

Comment: Your answer didn't work but it led me to the right direction. I replaced 'page' to 'page.driver' and it worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

On top, make sure you set `:js => true` like this:

```
scenario 'do something', :js => true do
    str = PDF::Inspector::Text.analyze(page.body).strings.join(" ") # or whatever string you want
    # then just use javascript to edit or add the body
    page.evaluate_script("document.write(#{str});")
end
```

Now this is dependent on the driver, but it's one solution...

Comment: i know this is my first answer on SO, but i've been lurking for a long time. cheers

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Then /^I should be served the document as a PDF$/ do
  page.response_headers['Content-Type'].should == "application/pdf"
  pdf = PDF::Inspector::Text.analyze(page.source).strings.join(" ")
  page.driver.response.instance_variable_set('@body', pdf)
end

Then /^I should see the document details$/ do
  page.should have_content("#{@document.customer.name}")
  page.should have_content("#{@document.resources.first.resource.name}")
  page.should have_content("Document opened at #{@document.created_at.strftime("%e-%b-%4Y %r")}")
end
```

Note that I'm serving my PDF inline

```
pdf = DocumentPdf.new(@document)
send_data pdf.render, :filename => "document_#{@document.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}",
  :type => "application/pdf",
  :disposition => "inline"
```